# BooleanArray with size larger than 2147483647

Tags: arrays, kotlin, type-mismatch, kotlin-native

I am trying to implement the sieve of Atkin in Kotlin. I want it to support numbers up to 2^32-1, so the sieve must be a `UInt`-indexed array.
I try to initialise the sieve like this:

```
var sieve = BooleanArray(limit + 1u)
```

Then, I get the error:

```
error: type mismatch: inferred type is UInt but Int was expected
```

So, is there any way of making a `BooleanArray` (or equivalent) store at least 4294967295 values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make REALLY large boolean arrays using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458489/how-do-you-make-really-large-boolean-arrays-using-java)

Comment: @shreyashshah That's absurd, because `Int` consumes more space than `Boolean` and the addressing by `Int` is the actual problem. This would have to be alike: [`BitArrayBin`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.activemq/activemq-core/5.7.0/org/apache/activemq/util/BitArrayBin.html), which addresses by `Long`. A custom implementation in Kotlin could even address by `UInt` or `ULong`.

Comment: Instead of an Integer array, use a binary array (less heavy).

Comment: Just a thought, (FYI, don't have much context of the problem), how about using integer array instead of boolean, where each element defines decimal number made from binary sequence of booleans. For example: if you are storing bool array as: [1, 0, 1, 0] it would be equivalent to [10] in int array. Now benifit of doing this is, say your bool array is of size 5x the size of uint limit with int array you will  have array of 5 integers where each element is decimal representation of 'x' booleans where x is size uint limit.

Comment: @Nandostyle Have you read the question or my comment? It reads `size: Int`, which is exactly the same problem and therefore wouldn't make the least difference, but only waste RAM.

Comment: Yeah please check my elaboration. In this case you will use more memory as compared to bool array but not by much extent. In worst case extra memory usage will be (int size - bool size).

Comment: An example, let's assume size of bool is 1bit and size of int is 4 bits. Now issue is you can't address bool array of size more than 4. Solution: imagine bool array is [ 1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0] (size 9) this won't be possible as we don't have enough int space to index 9 elements (we have 4) so what we do is use int array where we make integer out of every 4 booleans i.e. 1,0,1,0 =10 | 0,0,1,1 = 3 | 0 = 0 so array is [10,3, 0]  we just saved all the bools. cost was we used array size (3) * int size(4) = 12  bits i.e. 3 bits extra than original data. but this is worst case .

Comment: @shreyashshah think there is a 300% difference (assuming primitive data-types being used internally)... a [Judy array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array) might be the most extreme (it's overkill for the desired application), when it comes to handling large arrays.

Comment: 300% difference? Can you elaborate? @Martin Zeitler

Comment: It's `boolean` vs. `int` ...per each item. The most easy might be to use `UInt` as the size and then just internally map 2 common `BooleanArray`, which use `Int` for addressing, despite there never could be a negative index value (this seems to be a design fault - or at least a lack of optimization).

Comment: Or perhaps something like stream instead of an array? Idea comes from bitmaps and videos, if there are very large numbers of bitmaps coming as frames of a video in gfx world they treat the entire thing as a stream. Where only required subset of data gets queried and loaded for use at a time.

Comment: @Martin Zeitler You lost me around half way point, but yeah I would like to stand down from here on as don't have much knowledge of the subject, Kotlin in general. Just landed here looking at interesting title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easy might be to use `UInt` as the size and then internally map 2 common `BooleanArray`, which use `Int` for addressing, despite there never could be a negative index value (this seems to be a design fault - or at least a lack of optimization). Which means, that one could as well address everything with signed `Int`. I mean, to internally map the negative values to one `BooleanArray` and the positive values to another one `BooleanArray`. The actual problem seems to be, that a signed `Int` is being passed, but only the positive range (50%) can be used to address data. One could use [`absoluteValue`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/absolute-value.html#kotlin.math$absoluteValue#kotlin.Integer), because it doesn't matter in which direction the array is being filled.

Comment: I did manage to fix mine simply by using less memory. I used an algorithm that could do:  
`var sieve = BooleanArray((limit / 2u).toInt())`.  
But this will be useful for reference later. Thanks!